# Entity Framework - deleting an entity with more than one reference path to the same object

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, sql-server-2012

I would like to delete an entity that has a multi relationship to another entity.
In the Following example I would like to delete **DesignProject**

[image]

Problems:
a.
when I do not define any relation as cascade delete I get

```
  The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
```

when I do define both relations as cascade delete I can save the definition due to

```
  Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint '`' on table 'DesignItemAttributeValues' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths
```

when I mark only one I still get the confliction in the reference constraint

b.
And even if I could succeed I get an error trying to remove rows from DesignAttributeType because of the self reference.
Since I also can't define cascade delete on self-pointing foreign Keys I cant really delete rows.

So, can I delete this structure using EF or not?

Comment: No, you can't have 2 cascade paths from a table to another. So, the cascading deletes (at least partly) have to be dealt with code (a procedure or an instead trigger)

Comment: I understand I cant define two cascade path. But shouldnt I be able to define one path (i.e. through DesignAttributeTypes ) and define the connection between designItems and DesignAttributeValues as NoAction.
Logically, delete will delete eventually all of the data.

Comment: In taht case, what if you have a row in `DesignItemAttributeValues` that is only associated through `DesignItems`? The NoAction will forbid the delete.

Comment: Not possible. DesignItemsTypes is a key in DesignItemAttributes. So it must appear.

Comment: I was trying to be simple, sorry. Even in that case, there is no way to tell SQL-Server which of the cascade paths (that start from the `DesignProjects`) should be activated first on a delete. You want the path to `DesignAttributeTypes` first (and from that to `DesignItemAttributeValues`) and then to `DesignItems`. But SQL-Server may do it in any order,